# Node.js Express route-specific vs top-level generic parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What's the advantage of using top-level generic parsing:

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

instead of route-specific parsing:

```
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /newUser gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/newUser', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) {
      return res.sendStatus(400)
  } else {
  ...
  }
})
```

According to the body-parser [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/README.md) it says the route-specific is the most recommended way. Why? Why use it instead of top-level generic parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that executing the middleware unconditionally means you could be performing unnecessary work when the request already doesn't meet any preconditions, such as matching a route or meeting authentication requirements.